# Setting page title and keywords from PHP code

Tags: title

does WP offer any functions which can be used to set the page title and/or keywords from the PHP/Controller level?

I'm basically looking for something like the wp_enqueue_style() function, which results in changes to the HTML page header but for the title and keywords fields. I have some PHP code which dynamically retrieves/builds the page title and would like to avoid having to alter my theme/templates to display this.

Greetings/Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `wp_title` filter to modify the HTML document title, and you can use the `wp_head` action to hook in a custom HTML meta link. e.g.:

```
<?php
function wpse46249_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    // $title contains the default document title
    // output by WordPress. Modify it here however
    // you want.
    $some_custom_title_content = 'CUSTOM TITLE CONTENT HERE';
    // Now append it to the default
    $custom_title = $title . $some_custom_title_content;
    // Then return the result
    return $custom_title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse46249_filter_wp_title' );

function wpse46249_add_meta_link() {
    echo '<meta name="keywords" content="INSERT KEYWORDS HERE" />';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse46249_add_meta_link' );
?>
```

These callbacks can be added to a Plugin, to keep them safe from Theme switching.

For further reference, I would recommend taking a look at how the popular SEO Plugins implement these extensions.

Comment: @user13955 Here's links to the [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) and [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) hooks references from WordPress for more of a foundation on Chip's answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give this a try tomorrow morning. This seems to be exactly what I was looking for!